# On effects of dummy variables on scaled data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, normalization

I have a dataset consisting of 3 variables: a time series related to hourly energy load (expressed in thousands of MWh), a dummy variable related to business hours (e.g. the dummy is 1 the current hour is between 9-18, 0 otherwise) and one for weekend days (e.g. the dummy is 1 if it's Saturday or Sunday, 0 otherwise).
I want to perform a forecasting task on the energy load time series using the other two dummy variables as covariates. The forecasting will be performed with neural nets.

If I normalize the time series variable to a 0-1 scale, will the effect of the dummies be different in the prediction? What is usually the correct approach in these cases?

Note: the time series is stationary